# Deprecation of "replace" utility in mysql: what's the alternative?

Tags: mysql, replace

I use the [replace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace-utility.html) utility (mysql/5.7.21/bin/replace) in our scripts as it has pretty simple syntax and much easier to use in comparison to "sed".
However, with a mysql version upgrade, I have started getting the following:

```
Warning: replace is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
```

Noticed that the utility is planned to be removed with MySQL 8.0.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace-utility.html

Do we know about any similar alternative that MySQL is going to introduce?

Comment: This seems out of place, it has nothing to do with databases. I guess that's why they're removing it.

Comment: There is nothing at the official documentation also. So @Barmar 's reasoning makes complete sense and probably it is the right one. You can open a ticket on the MySQL board and see what they have to say about it.

Answer (score 3):

Answer by Bill Karwin is incorrect.

The `replace` utility shipped with various MySQL distributions and the one from `replace.richardlloyd.org.uk` are completely different programs, with different syntax and by different authors.

### Replace utility as shipped by MySQL

- Example use to illustrate syntax: `replace foo bar -- file.txt`. Multiple replacements can be specified by putting them before `--` delimiter, e.g.: `replace foo bar lorem ipsum -- file.txt`.
- Authored by someone named Monty and copyrighted by Oracle Corporation
- Case *sensitive* always

### Replace utility by Richard K. Lloyd

- Uses entirely different syntax. To specify multiple replacement pairs, `-a` switch can be used, e.g. `replace foo bar -a lorem ipsum file.txt`. Multiple `-a` switches can be used.
- Authored by Richard K. Lloyd
- Case *insensitive* by default. Case sensitive search can be enabled with `-e` switch.
- Is packaged as binary for CentOS / RHEL and can be deemed an alternative to users of `replace` utility shipped for MySQL:

As it put [here](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/replace), both programs have been packaged for CentOS / RHEL, e.g:

```
yum install https://extras.getpagespeed.com/release-el$(rpm -E %{rhel})-latest.rpm
```

Then, for Richard K. Lloyd's `replace`:

```
yum install replace2
```

Or, for the Oracle's `replace`:

```
yum install replace
```

Comment: I have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually over time I came across an alternate independent open-source utility that works more like replace and is available for both Linux and Mac: http://www.laffeycomputer.com/rpl.html

On Mac it can be installed using Homebrew:

```
brew install rpl
```

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL/MariaDB [`replace`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replace-utility/) utility is a hidden gem for blunt string replacements - last time I benchmarked this task, nothing came close to `replace`.

MariaDB does not seem to have deprecated this utility.

It's source code is available here: [extra/replace.c](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/3883eb63dc5e663558571c33d086c9fd3aa0cf8f/extra/replace.c) ([archived](http://web.archive.org/web/20230612125302/https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/3883eb63dc5e663558571c33d086c9fd3aa0cf8f/extra/replace.c)).